# Why ImportString[ExportString[, "PDF"], "PDF"] sometimes gives an extra point

Tags: plotting, pdf-format, fonts, mac-os-x

Consider this code:

```
fc = ImportString[ExportString[Style["Ma"], "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]];
lines = GeometricFunctions`DecodeFilledCurve[fc][[1]];
{lines // Length,Graphics[JoinedCurve[#]] & /@ lines}
```

will give what is expected:

[image]

but this code:

```
fc = ImportString[ExportString[Style["Ma", FontFamily -> "Times"], "PDF"], "PDF"][[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]];
lines = GeometricFunctions`DecodeFilledCurve[fc][[1]];
{lines // Length, Graphics[JoinedCurve[#]] & /@ lines}
```

gives four things, with the fourth element is just a point:

[image]

```
lines[[-1]]
(*{Line[{{10.5607,9.40406},{10.5607,9.40406}}]}*)
```

Why there is an extra point in the second case? I'm using version 9 on Mac.

**Update**

screenshots of the problem on version 8 and 9 on mac, and version 8 on windows 7, the results seems different:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't get the extra point.

Comment: I don't get it either (Win7, v9.01)

Comment: BTW The first picture is *not* created by the first block of code.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: Ok, so it is OS dependent then. Unfortunately, I can't help with that as I don't have OSX. I assume that it is caused by its PDF exporter. There is a remote possibility that it may be a problem of the font itself.

Comment: Not sure why `Times` looks different on Mac, but you could work around it by replacing `Times` with `TimesNewRoman`.

Comment: @Jens So another way of distinguishing between Times and Times New Roman...! :) The problem also appears in some other fonts, eg a Helvetica "g" (but not Helvetica Neue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered this problem, coming from a slightly different direction. I think the compound paths contain an extra pair of coordinates that you're noticing when you split up the results of a `FilledCurve`.

Here's how I first came across this:

```
glyph[code_, font_, size_] := 
  First[First[
    ImportString[
     ExportString[
      Style[FromCharacterCode[code], FontSize -> size, 
       FontFamily -> font], "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]]; 

a = glyph[97, "Times", 24]
```

```html
{Thickness[0.130073],
  {FilledCurve[
    {
      {{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,3}},
      {{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,3}, ...
      {{0,2,0}}},
     {
      {{3.74836,5.265},{4.01063,5.265},{4.25426,5.35078}, ...
      {{0.405,5.96742},{0.405,6.74086},{0.77502,7.35469}, ...
      {{4.1175,12.4875},{4.1175,12.4875}}}]}}
```

The `{{4.1175,12.4875},{4.1175,12.4875}}` is a short zero-length line that I think might be causing the problems.

I noticed it when I selected the graphic. I could see that there was something odd there:

```
Graphics[{Gray, a}]
```

[image: the letter a selected]

The short line registers oddly as a large dot.

Looking at all the letter forms, it appears that you definitely get this extra line for many letters, not just for "compound paths".

```
Length[#[[2, 1, 1, 2]]] & /@ (glyph[#, "Helvetica", 24] & /@ 
   ToCharacterCode /@ Characters["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]);
BarChart[%, ChartLabels -> Characters["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]]
```

[image: chart]

There's "a", "e", and "o" which have three elements in the relevant `FilledCurve`.  "b" has two, like it should have, but "c" should only have one. "n", "s", and "u" also have more elements than they need. And so on.

You could probably fix this by adding a rule that makes zero-length lines get deleted from the `FilledCurve`, but that's proved beyond my expertise...

tl;dr I think it's a bug, but who knows whether in *Mathematica* or the Mac OS system.