# Is possible to embed a text on a face grid in Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, labeling

I am trying to embed a text on the left  `FaceGrid` (such that it looks like it is written on the respective `FaceGrid`), how can I do that?

```
Graphics3D[{}, AspectRatio -> 1, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{Bottom, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}}, {Left, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 
      2}}}, {Back, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}}}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Rotate[Inset[
    Framed[Style["Text", 18, White, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], 
     Background -> Black], Scaled[{.15, 0.50}]], \[Pi]/4]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
left = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}};
back = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};
bottom = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};

vtc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}; 

text = {Texture[Rasterize[Text[Framed[
  Style["Some Text", Yellow, Bold, FontSize -> 46, FontFamily -> "Old English Text MT"],
     FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> Scaled[.02]]], Background -> Black]], 
  Polygon[left, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]};

moretext = {Texture[Rasterize[Text[Framed[
   Style["more Text", White, Bold, FontSize -> 46, FontFamily -> "Lucida Handwriting"], 
    FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> Scaled[.02]]], Background -> Red]], 
   Polygon[back, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]};

etcetc = {Texture[Rasterize[Text[Framed[
   Style["ETC ETC ...", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 46, FontFamily -> "Euclid Fraktur"], 
     FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> Scaled[.02]]], Background -> None]], 
   Polygon[bottom, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc]};


Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5, Blue], Sphere[{1, 1, 1}/2, 1/4], Opacity[0], 
     Cuboid[]}, text, moretext, etcetc}, 
   Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@kglr! that is cool, Is it possible to add the text only to part of the face, say at the corner inside a square box?  The same text box in the question I would like to add at only at the corner of the left  FaceGrid.

Comment: @HD2006, you can specify the polygon coordinates as you like. Try for example, `left =left/3` before you execute the line `text = ...`.

Answer (score 3):

This is doable, but for a long time with difficulties. It is possible that the difficulties I mention below doesn't exist anymore, but in case they are still there, it is preferable that you have a overview of what's coming.

You can do it with `ImportString[ExportString["Text BlabBlah","PDF"],"PDF"]` which returns the graphic primitives corresponding to the text (in 2D, but it is not a problem to transform it in 3D).

The problem is that you may encounter [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25010/5467) , which is **OS dependent**.

In this case there is a workaround, but it uses a [undocumented syntax of FilledCurve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/563/5467)

One more information : It it perfectly possible to add a Style to the text :

`ImportString[ExportString[Style["Blah  Blah", FontSize -> 60], "PDF"],
   "PDF"] // First`

Comment: I would be pleased to be informed that this problem is solved, but as it is OS dependent, it will be hard to know if the solution is definitive.

Comment: I don't get it, may you please incorporate the solution into the above code?

Comment: Effectively, even the conversion of ImportString[ExportString["Text BlabBlah","PDF"],"PDF"] to a 3D object on not that simple. kglr's solution is better.