# Facing text in 3D graphics with full options

Tags: graphics3d, style, text

I'm seeking a refinement/extension of the excellent and very valuable solution appearing [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131798/placing-text-in-3d-not-facing-viewer).

That solution indeed allows you to place text anywhere in a 3D graphics and then rotate it (by Euler angles) so it faces any direction you like.

*However*... it has two important limitations for my application:

- For some reason it does not handle subscripts and superscripts:  they are lost and not rendered
- The solution does not allow a background color, such as `Background -> White`.  (I need this when I'm placing a label atop a black line and want to hide a short section of the line.)

In sum:  I'm hoping to get a version of `text3D` that could work with `Style`, of the form:

```
text3D[Style[Subscript[x, o], Italic, 24, Background->Yellow], 
{x-position, y-position, z-position}, 
EulerAngle1, EulerAngle2, EulerAngle3]
```

Minor point:  I think the Euler angles should be grouped into a `List`... but again, minor suggestion:

```
text3D[Style[Subscript[x, o], Italic, 24, Background->Yellow], 
{x-position, y-position, z-position}, 
{EulerAngle1, EulerAngle2, EulerAngle3}]
```

Here's an example of what I'm seeking, where I used `text3D`:

[image: episcope]

My original file is .eps (and .pdf) [I had to convert it to .png to upload to this site.]  The labels on the artwork and mirror were created using `text3D` and have that wonderful orientation, as desired.  However, the labels along the bottom do NOT have that orientation.  I added them as standard `Text` in order to get the subscripts and `Background -> White` to cover the lines.

*THAT* is the problem I'd like to fix.

Comment: The original eps maybe create by Tikz or Asymptote etc. which support 3D TeX label.

Comment: Does Tikz or Asymptote allow transparency of surfaces?  (I need that too.). I also use *Optica* to create ray-tracing diagrams (e.g., green rays), and this is fully integrated with *Mathematica*.  How would I do that with Tikz or Asymptote?  I do presume you can map a texture (such as those paintings) onto a curved surface such as a barrel in Tikz or Asymptote.... right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you could use an adapted version of the `billboard3D` function that I adapted from a previous answer here [How to write graffiti, i.e., text on a polygon surface in Graphics3D?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228625/61809) that I ultimately adapted from a Wolfram-U video presentation
[Advanced 3D Graphics in the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/vis422/). It uses normals rather than Euler angles, but it should be straightforward to convert to the flavor of Euler angles you desire. Here is an example:

```
Clear[billboard3D];
billboard3D[s_, 
   width_, {x_, y_, z_}, {nx_, ny_, nz_}, {hx_, hy_, hz_}, 
   bkgrd_ : None, raster_ : 1000] :=
  Module[{img = 
     Rasterize[s, "Image", Background -> bkgrd, RasterSize -> raster],
     height},
   height = width ImageAspectRatio[img];
   {
    FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[],
    Texture[ImageData[img]],
    GeometricTransformation[
     Polygon[{{-.5 width, .5 height, 0}, {.5 width, .5 height, 
        0}, {.5 width, -.5 height, 0}, {-.5 width, -.5 height, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}],
     Quiet@
      Composition[TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}], 
       RotationTransform[{{0, 1, 0}, {hx, hy, hz}}], 
       RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {nx, ny, nz}}]]]
    }
   ];

Framed[
 Graphics3D[{
   
   (* Add a Plot3D Object *)
   Plot3D[ 
     0.9 Exp[-9 ((x - 1/2)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2)], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 2}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Red]][[1]],
   (* View frustum *)
   FaceForm[], EdgeForm[GrayLevel[.25]], Cuboid[],
   
   (* Camera *)
   FaceForm[GrayLevel[.25]], EdgeForm[], Specularity[White, 30],
   Cuboid[{.45, -1, .4}, {.55, -1.3, .6}],
   Cylinder[{{.475, -1.1, .65}, {.525, -1.1, .65}}, .05],
   Cylinder[{{.475, -1.2, .65}, {.525, -1.2, .65}}, .05],
   Cylinder[{{.5, -1, .5}, {.5, -.9, .5}}, .05],
   Cylinder[{{.5, -1.15, .5}, {.5, -.9, 0}}, .01],
   Cylinder[{{.5, -1.15, .5}, {.35, -1.3, 0}}, .01],
   Cylinder[{{.5, -1.15, .5}, {.65, -1.3, 0}}, .01],
   billboard3D[
    Style["ViewPoint", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .4, {.5, -1.15, .8}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}],
   
   (* View span *)
   GrayLevel[.25],
   With[{p = {.5, -.9, .5}}, 
    Line[{{p, {0, 0, 0}}, {p, {1, 0, 0}}, {p, {0, 0, 1}}, {p, {1, 0, 
        1}}}]],
   
   (* View angle *)
   Gray, Dashed,
   With[{p = {.5, -.9, .5}}, Line[{{p, {.5, 0, 1}, {.5, 0, 0}, p}}]],
   Arrowheads[{-.015, .015}], 
   Arrow[BezierCurve[{{.5, -.5, 
       0.28}, {.5, -.4, .5}, {.5, -.5, .72}}]],
   billboard3D[
    Style["ViewAngle", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .3, {.5, -.4, .45}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}],
   
   (* View vertical *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["ViewVertical", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {.5, -.05, .75}, {1, 0, 
     0}, {0, -1, 0}],
   
   (* View center *)
   PointSize[Large], Point[{{.5, .5, .5}, {.5, 0, .5}}],
   Arrowheads[.015], Arrow[{{.5, .5, .5}, {.5, 0, .5}}],
   billboard3D[
    Style["ViewCenter", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .25, {.5, .25, .55}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}],
   
   (* View range *)
   Gray,
   Line[{{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, -.1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, -.1}}}],
   Arrowheads[{-.02, .02}], Arrow[{{1, 0, -0.05}, {1, 1, -.05}}],
   billboard3D[
    Style["ViewRange", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .4, {1.075, .5, -.1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0,
      1}],
   
   (* View left wall *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Left\), \(Wall\)]\)", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {0, 0.5, .5}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}, Yellow],
   
   (* View right wall *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Right\), \(Wall\)]\)", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {1, 0.5, .5}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
     1}, Green],
   
   (* View top wall *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["Top Wall", 24, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {0.5, 
     0.5, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}],
   
   (* View bottom wall *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["Bottom Wall", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {0.5, 0.5, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
     0}],
   
   (* View front wall *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["Front Wall", 24, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {0.5,
      0, 0.5}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}],
   
   (* View back wall *)
   billboard3D[
    Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Back\), \(Wall\)]\)", 24, Bold, 
     FontFamily -> "Courier"], .35, {0.5, 1, 0.5}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 
     1}, Orange]
   
   },
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 750, Lighting -> "Neutral",
  ViewPoint -> {5, -2, 1.5}
  ],
 FrameMargins -> 20, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.75]]
```

[image]

## Update

I modified the `billboard3D` function to pass in an Euler angles and a translation list. In the process of testing the function, I noticed that it was difficult to match a white background, as shown below:

[image: Off-white background]

I could circumvent the issue by supplying a White [`Glow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Glow.html) directive to Graphics3D as shown in the following workflow:

```
Clear[transformFn]
transformFn[angles_List, translation_List] := Module[{m},
  (* Set up Transform Function*)
  m = IdentityMatrix[4];
  (* Rotation Part *)
  m[[1 ;; 3, 1 ;; 3]] = EulerMatrix[angles];
  (* Translation Part *)
  m[[1 ;; 3, -1]] = translation;
  TransformationFunction[m]
  ]
Clear[billboard3DEuler];
billboard3DEuler[s_, width_, angles_List, translation_List, 
   bkgrd_ : None, raster_ : 1000] := 
  Module[{img = 
     Rasterize[s, "Image", Background -> bkgrd, RasterSize -> raster],
     height}, height = width ImageAspectRatio[img];
   {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[], Texture[ImageData[img]], 
    GeometricTransformation[
     Polygon[{{-.5 width, .5 height, 0}, {.5 width, .5 height, 
        0}, {.5 width, -.5 height, 0}, {-.5 width, -.5 height, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
     Quiet@transformFn[angles, translation]]}];
(*Set up unit vectors*)
null = {0, 0, 0};
(* Unit Vectors *)
{ex, ey, ez} = UnitVector[3, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
(*Create reference axes*)
axesfn = {Red, Arrow[Tube[{null, #1 ex}, #2]], Green, 
    Arrow[Tube[{{null, #1 ey}}, #2]], Blue, 
    Arrow[Tube[{{null, #1 ez}}, #2]]} &;
axes = Graphics3D@axesfn[4, 0.04];
(*Manipulate rotation and translation*)
Manipulate[Show[{axes, Graphics3D[{
     (* View left wall *)
     Glow[White], 
     billboard3DEuler[
      Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(o\)]\)", 24,(*Bold,*)
       FontFamily -> "Lucida Calligraphy"], 
      1.5, {Dynamic@α, Dynamic@β, 
       Dynamic@γ}, {Dynamic@x, Dynamic@y, Dynamic@z}, White, 
      500]
     }]}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {Infinity, Infinity, Infinity},
   PlotRange -> 4 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-0.5, 1}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {{α, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}, {{β, 0}, 
  0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}, {{γ, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/2}, {{x, 0}, -2, 
  2}, {{y, 0}, -2, 2}, {{z, 0}, -2, 2}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Manipulate animation]

Comment: This is very nice ($+1$) but `text3D` preserved *eps* format and didn't have to rasterize.  Any way to ensure the eps format?  (I couldn't figure it out *and* retain subscripts.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Thanks.  I will have to investigate a bit.  It may be difficult since we are using textures to create the effect.  I have only done that with images.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The text3D function used `DiscretizeGraphics` to convert the text into a mesh.  Therefore, the eps format is not preserved.  I added a `raster` option to the `billboard3D` function.  You can increase the resolution of the font by increasing the raster size.

Comment: Ah yes, now that you pointed it out even `text3D` uses `Raster`.  (So now I *really* don't understand the loss of subscripts!). Anyway, given all this, I think yours is acceptable ($\checkmark$).  I do think *Mathematica* should, in future versions, support this kind of text orientation functionality *in .eps*.  It really helps in certain complex figures.

Comment: Oh... thanks for the extra work.  Except for the `Rasterize` (which may be necessary, but shouldn't be!), this is just what I need.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You are welcome! I do not necessarily disagree about eps, but there could be more to the story. When I was experimenting with some font families, there were many whose resolution did not improve with increasing raster size. I am assuming (perhaps wrongly) that Mathematica could not find PostScript versions of that font family on my system.

Comment: Oh... I'm happy to use a similar font to my preference (Latin Modern Roman... as used in *LaTeX*) if that ensures .eps.