# embedded text in Graphics3D does not appear when exported as pdf?

Tags: graphics, export

I am using this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228623/how-to-write-graffiti-i-e-text-on-a-polygon-surface-in-graphics3d) to embed text in  `Graphics3D` (MMA12.2.0.0, win64) but when exported as pdf the text disappears?

here is the first part of the code from the mentioned answer

```
Clear[billboard3D];
billboard3D[s_, 
   width_, {x_, y_, z_}, {nx_, ny_, nz_}, {hx_, hy_, hz_}] := 
  Module[{img = Rasterize[s, "Image", Background -> None], height}, 
   height = width ImageAspectRatio[img];
   {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[None], Texture[ImageData[img]], 
    GeometricTransformation[
     Polygon[{{-.5 width, .5 height, 0}, {.5 width, .5 height, 
        0}, {.5 width, -.5 height, 0}, {-.5 width, -.5 height, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
     Quiet@Composition[TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}], 
       RotationTransform[{{0, 1, 0}, {hx, hy, hz}}], 
       RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {nx, ny, nz}}]]]}];
```

and then  I use it to insert the text as follows

```
Module[{op = 0.1}, 
 plot = Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cuboid[{6, 0, 0}, {10, 6, 5}], Red, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cuboid[{6, 0, 5}, {10, 6, 10}], Opacity[1], 
    billboard3D[Style["HM", 50, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
     3.5, {10, 3, 7}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}], 
    billboard3D[Style["DFN", 50, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
     5, {10, 3, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]}, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 230, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, -1.5, 0.5}]]
```

Now, this is what I get when export as pdf using `Export["....plot.pdf", plot, ImageResolution -> 800]`

[image]

the `Cuboid`s are very clean but the text doesn't appear!

Then I tried to export as png and this the results

[image]

Now I get the text but its background is not the same as the `Cuboid`  and the `Cuboid` are not clean and smooth as in the pdf?!

--------------**Update**---------------

I tried also MMA 12.1.1.0 on Ubuntu 18 and this is what obtained when exported as pdf:

[image]

-------------------**update 2**---------

the created pdf file by Mathematic is [attached](https://www.dropbox.com/s/setw6y76i50sbi4/plotb3.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried with multiple pdf readers? For example, Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: @CarlLange, yes, I tried also Foxit and both show the same result.

Comment: I tried this earlier today in 12.2 and it was fine for me. So something else might be in play.

Comment: @ihojnicki, I tried that on Ubuntu 18 with MMA 12.1.1.0 and the same result, kindly see the udates.

Comment: I've tried on MMA 12.3 on MacOS and it looks almost completely ok. You can try setting `EdgeDepthOffset->True` in `Graphics3D` or changing the `RenderingOptions`

Comment: @valarmorghulis can you please have a look at my updated answer and let me know if what I suggested is towards what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this fully fixes the problem, but I observe a better image.

Firstly, I am using

```
$Version
12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)
```

Now, what I did is the following:

1. I run the code precisely as it is given in the post and generating an image
2. Right click on the image, `Print Graphic`, I chose Print to File (PDF), and then just clicked the Print button.

I obtain the following -I just converted it to .png online to be able to post it here. The result seems to be a small improvement compared to the images in the OP I think

[image]

Edit: after some comments regarding the issue, I suggest the following:

The code from the OP is given below for convenience

```
Clear[billboard3D];
billboard3D[s_, 
   width_, {x_, y_, z_}, {nx_, ny_, nz_}, {hx_, hy_, hz_}] := 
  Module[{img = Rasterize[s, "Image", Background -> None], height}, 
   height = width ImageAspectRatio[img];
   {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[None], Texture[ImageData[img]], 
    GeometricTransformation[
     Polygon[{{-.5 width, .5 height, 0}, {.5 width, .5 height, 
        0}, {.5 width, -.5 height, 0}, {-.5 width, -.5 height, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
     Quiet@Composition[TranslationTransform[{x, y, z}], 
       RotationTransform[{{0, 1, 0}, {hx, hy, hz}}], 
       RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {nx, ny, nz}}]]]}];

Module[{op = 0.1}, 
 plot = Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cuboid[{6, 0, 0}, {10, 6, 5}], Red, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[None], 
    Cuboid[{6, 0, 5}, {10, 6, 10}], Opacity[1], 
    billboard3D[Style["HM", 50, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
     3.5, {10, 3, 7}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}], 
    billboard3D[Style["DFN", 50, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
     5, {10, 3, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]}, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 230, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, -1.5, 0.5}]]
```

Then we use

```
test = Graphics3D[
   Inset[plot, ImageScaled[{1, 1, 0}], {Center, Center}, 230], 
   AbsoluteOptions[plot], ImageSize -> 230];
Export["figure.pdf", test]
```

which produces the following (as before I only used an online converter to make it a .png to be able to post it here; on my laptop I have precisely the same .pdf file)

[image]

This approach can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file) amongst other ones as well.

Final edit:

I took a screenshot of the .pdf file itself, just to demonstrate that the image is clear -at least on my laptop- and perhaps there is another issue; version of Mathematica(?), document viewer, etc??

This is the screenshot

[image]

I am using the standard document viewer of Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But still, I think there must be an elegant solution to this where we can be `Exporte`

Comment: @valarmorghulis hopefully there is an easy fix to it. sure. I just suggested the above as an alternative in order to maintain the .pdf character of the exported graph. Do I understand correctly that you are not interested so much in changing to .png or something else? and also, did my proposed solution work well enough for you? if not, maybe there is something else messing things up

Comment: The problem is that I want to sign a specific resolution to the plot. your solution on my machine produces the pdf but with fuzzy resolution. Yes, I want a vector version of the plot, not jpg

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll give it another go bit later to see if I can come up with something better

Comment: Thanks a lot for the efforts!

Comment: the approach in the updated answer gives a very NICE png but for the pdf still the same where the text does not appear as in the original question.

Comment: @valarmorghulis  I am getting a very nice looking .pdf file as well, this is why I suggested this approach. I am just using the standard document viewer of Ubuntu. I have included a screenshot to demonstrate. Perhaps you are facing another issue, like mma version, document viewer, or something related?

Comment: thanks a lot, it is also working and produces a very nice fig here on Ubuntu. I don't know why on windows it is not working! Thanks again for the efforts!

Comment: @valarmorghulis glad to hear that you were able to make progress. I do not have Windows available and cannot possibly make any comments. I haven't used them in a while to be honest :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Module[{op = 0.1}, plot = Style[Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[None], 
 Cuboid[{6, 0, 0}, {10, 6, 5}], Red, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[None], 
 Cuboid[{6, 0, 5}, {10, 6, 10}], Opacity[1], 
 billboard3D[Style["HM", 50, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
  3.5, {10, 3, 7}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}], 
 billboard3D[Style["DFN", 50, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier"], 
  5, {10, 3, 3}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}]}, Axes -> False, 
ImageSize -> 230, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, -1.5, 0.5}], RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "BSPTree"}]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing thoughts, that solves the problem when exported as png but with pdf still the same problem.

Comment: maybe additionally use ```Export["plot.pdf", Graphics[Inset[plot, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]]```? @valarmorghulis

Comment: @Xuemei, thanks for the comment, but the problem still  presents

Comment: Can you attach or send me the generated pdf? Worth checking if it's a problem with MMA exporter or PDF reader/OS.

Comment: @Ranza I checked with different pdf editors but not working too. Kindly see the updates I attached the pdf.

Comment: @valarmorghulis right, thanks!

Comment: @valarmorghulis a quick question as I just saw the updates: the problem is on Wndows, yes? if you use Ubuntu you should be able to get a nice .pdf file or did I misunderstand? maybe you should add this in the OP as well

Comment: @valarmorghulis another trivial thought: you could `Rasterize@` the result just before exporting. It's not going to be vector graphics, but it's almost guaranteed to look properly.

Comment: Yes, the problem with windows now only. Ok, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Ranza  `Rasterize` does the job perfectly, Thanks!